# How to generate a fixed-length hash based on current date and time in Python?

Tags: python, datetime, hash

I want to generate a fixed-length (say 10 characters) hash based on current date & time. This hash will be append to names of the uploaded files from my users. How can I do that in Python?

Comment: Why not just use an integer time stamp?  ie. the number of seconds since some starting time, typically January 1st 1970 (the unix epoch).  This would be a 10 digit integer.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Batteries included:

## Python3

```py
import hashlib
import time

hashlib.sha1().update(str(time.time()).encode("utf-8"))
print(hashlib.sha1().hexdigest())
print(hashlib.sha1().hexdigest()[:10])
```

## Python2

```
import hashlib
import time

hash = hashlib.sha1()
hash.update(str(time.time()))
print hash.hexdigest()
print hash.hexdigest()[:10]
```

Comment: for python 3.0 and above, you will need to encode the timestamp string in encoding of choice to avoid getting an error, e.g. ```str(time.time()).encode('utf-8')```. Just putting it out there for python3 users.

Comment: I'm getting the same answer every time with any random integer

Answer (score 5):

I think my comment is a reasonable answer so I am going to post it.  The code uses the python [time()](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.time) function to get the number of seconds since the unix epoch:

```
import time
import datetime
ts = int(time.time())  # this removes the decimals

# convert the timestamp to a datetime object if you want to extract the date
d = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts)
```

The time stamp is currently a 10 digit integer that can easily be converted back to a datetime object for other uses.  If you want to further shrink the length of the timestamp you could encode the number in hexadecimal or some other format.   ie.

```
hex(int(time.time()))
```

This reduces the length to 8 characters if you remove the `0x` prefix

EDIT:

In your comment you specified that you don't want people to figure out the original date so I would suggest doing something like:

```
hex(int(time.time() + 12345))[2:]   #The [2:] removes the 0x prefix
```

Just chose a number and remember to subtract it when you are trying to extract the timestamp.  Without knowing this number the user would have a very difficult time inferring the real date from your code.

```
int(stamp,16) - 12345
```

Comment: This is nice but I want to apply some hashing algorithm as I want to hide the source of the hash (ex. timestamp)

Comment: If you hex encode it and chose a non-standard epoch it would be quite difficult for anyone to infer the original date

Comment: Good point. What would you do if the requirement becomes 12 characters instead of 10?

Comment: @ahmoo:  You could always add a very large number to the timestamp to create a 12 digit number or you could just add two random hex characters to each string.  You would know which two characters are randomly generated but the user wouldn't. The advantage of this scheme is that the hash is easily reversible if you ever wanted to retrieve the timestamp from the file name.

Comment: Your solution is fine. Thanks. I, however, have decided to go with @FerdinandBeyer, simply because I don't really need the hash to be reversible.

Comment: When dealing with HIPAA indexing, it is a requirement that it be non-reversible.

Answer (score 2):

```
import time
'{0:010x}'.format(int(time.time() * 256))[:10]
```

Comment: If you just want to format a value without embedding it in template string, I suggest you use the `format()` function instead of `str.format()`: `format(int(time.time() * 256), '010x')`.  It's cleaner and (slightly) faster.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [strftime](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) for python.  You can format the date/time string any number of ways to get the 'look' you want.

Answer (score 0):

What about changing the base of current milliseconds since epoch. For example, in JavaScript, changing to base 36:

```
Date.now().toString(36)
```

Results in :

```
"jv8pvlbg"
```

That should be a safe hash, up to milliseconds, respect date order and smaller than 10.

The only thing is that is not safe, but in your case security is not important right?

Sorry I don't have the answer for python, but it should by straightforward and should nor require any library. My two cents.

Comment: Python requested, yet I like the concept.